# Is there a way to find all the attributes of a primitive in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, primitive, primitive-types

In Python, for example, I can use

```
dir(str)
```

to find all the attributes and methods of the string data type.

Is there something similar in Javascript?

Just want additional info on JavaScript primitives. It's not an actual coding problem. Thanks.

Comment: There are only a few primitive types in JS and their methods are defined on the respective `prototype` property of each constructor, e.g. `String.prototype`. These are objects, so you can use [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptors) on those, or on any other object, or on `Object(str)`. Note that `String.prototype` is an excellent example of why you _must_ read the documentation instead of simply looking at method names. Most of these methods are deprecated, e.g. `big`, `bold`, `fontcolor`, …

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74707759/is-there-a-way-to-find-all-the-attributes-of-a-primitive-in-javascript#comment131855619_74707759) @Etheryte I agree that documentation is a great source (it is almost always my primary), but there's never a guarantee that it 100% reflects the nature of the current environment (there are many JS runtime environments and each one implements a subset and superset of the spec). In cases where you want to know with certainty and **exact** detail the nature of your environment, introspection/analysis is always better than documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let o = Object.getPrototypeOf('string') // equals to String.prototype

for (let k of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o)) {
    console.log(k, o[k])
}
```

same for all other primitives (number `123`, BigInt `123n`, symbol `Symbol('symbolDesc')`)

Note however that some of them may be deprecated (mainnly string functions which wrap `text.bold() == '<b>'+text+'</b>'`  and alike)

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @Tal if this answers your question, makr it as answer